# Is my orchid diseased?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, diseases, leaves, orchids

I bought a pair of Vanda orchids online. One of them looks fine and healthy but the other one had black bruising on the leaves more than halfway up the plant.

The articles I read.on the net suggest that black spots that increase in size indicate fungal infection. However, these do Not look like spots - but long stretches of bruising like on a banana skin.

I am not sure as to what corrective action to take till I can figure out what exactly is wrong with it.

[image: to]

Orchid pros: any thoughts?

As per recommendations on the net, I need to chop off all the infected parts. Will I be able to keep this plant alive if I have to take out more than 3/4rh of it from the bottom, including roots?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question and good illustration; if could include a closer illustration of the leaves & closer illustration of the marring on the leaves, overall height, current watering and misting amount & frequency, current nutrient type & amount & frequency, average daytime temperature, average night time temperature, number of hours of direct sunlight per day, and number of hours of diffused light per day, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help] to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Does it rain often where you're from?  Or is that water from you?  Does the spotted one receive more sunlight than the other orchid in the back?

The roots look healthy.  If it rains frequently where you are, I would suggest dialing back your own watering.  If that's already happening, I would suggest moving it to another tree -- they tend to love bright areas but not necessarily direct sunlight (they tend to be shaded by other trees or rocks in nature).  The spots look similar to burns more than rot/disease, could they be facing something reflective that makes sunlight even more offensive?

I hope you can keep it, it is a beautiful plant.